# ¿Qué hace git restore --staged y git rm --cached?

Tags: git, github

¿Qué hace `git restore --staged` y en que se diferencia

de `git reset HEAD` y `git rm --cached`?

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: [`git restore - - staged`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore#Documentation/git-restore.txt---staged), [`git-reset`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) y [`git-rm`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm)

Answer (score 2):

Son tres funciones distintas.

`git restore --staged <archivo>`: como indica su nombre, quita el archvo de la fase *stage*. El stage es la fase previa por la que pasa un archivo antes de ser *commiteado*

`git reset HEAD -- <archivo>`:  El *HEAD* es por así decirlo un puntero que te situa en que parte de la rama te encuentras ahora mismo, esta instrucción lo que hace es devolver al archivo al estado en el que estaba el commit donde se encuentra el *HEAD*.

`git rm --cached <archivo>`: Lo que hace es borrar el archivo del árbol de trabajo de GIT. El archivo seguirá en tu directorio, pero GIT no lo traqueará, es decir para GIT es como si no existiera.

Luego las diferencias entre los tres son `git restore --staged <archivo>` simplemente **quita el archivo del stage**. `git reset HEAD -- <archivo>` devuelve el archivo al commit donde se encuentra el *HEAD*, es decir **lo modifica** hacia un estado anterior y `git rm --cached <archivo>` hace que git **deje de realizar seguimiento** del archivo.