# ¿Diferencia entre git restore --staged y git reset HEAD?

Tags: git, github, repositorio

**Es que estuve viendo que ambos se usan para sacar archivos del area de staging. Hace unos años, git te recomendaba git reset HEAD, pero ahora te recomienda git restore --staged. ¿Hay algo que haga diferente a estos comandos?**

Comment: ¿Podrías indicar _dónde_ lo están recomendando?

Comment: en Git Bash, cuando agregas un archivo al staging area

Comment: Hola Alex! Ya hiciste esta pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/466792/qu%c3%a9-hace-git-restore-staged-y-git-rm-cached y tienes un comentario y una respuesta, lo adecuado en el caso de que no te sirvan es realizar comentarios en la misma pregunta, no crear otra pregunta igual

Answer (score 0):

Ambos comandos pueden ser usados para realizar la misma acción.

```
git restore --staged
```

Es usado para quitar los archivos del area provisional (stagged area), el contenido se restaura desde el `HEAD`. Por ejemplo cuando por accidente los agregaste a el area provisional y deseas deshacer el cambio.

```
git reset HEAD
```

Es usado para quitar los archivos del area provisional (stagged area), pero en este caso puedes también indicar que archivo o archivos deseas quitar del area provisional,  ejemplo:

```
git reset HEAD <file>
```

---

Puedes revisar la documentación:

[GIT Deshacer cosas](https://git-scm.com/book/es/v2/Fundamentos-de-Git-Deshacer-Cosas)

[Git git restore](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore)

Comment: gracias, pero con restore --staged tambien se puede especificar el archivo

Comment: Si, comento que también se puede usar, en realidad como comento ambos se pueden usar para lo mismo. Tal vez la recomendación era por usar por equivocación git reset --hard HEAD en lugar de solo  git reset HEAD

Comment: Tranqui, entiendo, gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Una cosa mas, que hace git reset --hard HEAD?

Comment: Elimina cualquier cambio hasta el último commit (excepto los archivos que no tienes trackeados en git, claro). Incluso puedes añadir ~1 para eliminar incluso el último commit... o cualquier otro nº de commits

Comment: si, como comenta Benito y se descartara cualquier cambio no confirmado que tengas :-/.